# Recommendations on PPV Video Service

Tags: php, pay-per-view

I've been asked to create a PHP PPV video site and before I go off reinventing the wheel I'd like to make sure there isn't some canned solution that does exactly or nearly what I'm looking for. Let me explain my requirements, I need:

1. Galleries of videos organized by category or tag or something (flexible here)
2. Ability to comment on / rate videos
3. Ability to charge for video access in a number of ways including:

   - 24hr rental of a video for X credits
   - Yearlong (or maybe lifetime) rental of a video for Y credits
   - Ability to purchase credits in blocks of $Z
   - Permanent full subscription to the site (essentially unlimited credits) for a monthly fee
4. These would be static videos uploaded by an admin. Live video is NOT needed and I don't expect to have a need to allow user uploads either.

Is there ANYTHING like this out there or at least anything close that could be presumably altered to fit the need? Not afraid of doing digging around into PHP source or altering DB tables.